# Split method not working in shapely?

Tags: python, shapely

The following two scripts are very similar in that they both make use of the `interpolate` method to create a point along the line, and then attempt to split the line based on that point. The variable `r` represents the geometry collections object that is returned after the split. Logically speaking, and in both cases the length should equal 2 corresponding to each split segment however the following script

```
from shapely.geometry import Point,LineString
from shapely import ops
A = Point(0,0)
B = Point(1,1)
C = Point(2,1.5)
ABC = LineString([A,B,C])
point = ABC.interpolate(1.973)
r = ops.split(ABC,point)
print(len(r))
```

returns `2` which means that it succeeded in splitting the linestring object and the following script

```
from shapely import ops,wkt
linestring = wkt.loads('LINESTRING (2156463.403842391 5163459.650219071, 2156468.97841872 5163460.757960646, 2156479.958830318 5163465.350633934)')
point = linestring.interpolate(7.000000000)
r = ops.split(linestring,point)
print(len(r))
```

returns a `1` which means it didn't.

Why does the first script work and the other not?

Comment: I don't know why, but `interpolate` seems to be picky about what parameter you put in. Your second example with `wkt.loads` works if I put it the same numbers as in example 1.

Comment: But I want to use the other set of numbers... that's my real use case